# Set part of grep to variable

Tags: linux, grep, text-processing

```
mysqladmin proc status | grep "Threads"
```

Output:

```
Uptime: 2304  Threads: 14  Questions: 2652099  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 48791  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 4000  Queries per second avg: 1151.08
```

I would like to set it so `$mysqlthread` would output `14` after running `echo $mysqlthread`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is with Perl instead of grep.

```
mysqladmin proc status | perl -nle'/Threads: (\d+)/ && print $1'
```

perl -n means "go through each line of input".

perl -l means "print a \n at the end of every `print`"

perl -e means "here is my program"

`/Threads: (\d+)/` means "match `Threads:`  followed by one or more digits.  And `print $1` means "print the digits I found as denoted by the parentheses around `\d+`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`

```
$ mysqlthread=$(mysqladmin proc status | grep -Po 'Threads: \K\d+')
$ echo "$mysqlthread"
14
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. This is one:

```
mysqladmin proc status | grep "Threads" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4
```

The `tr` command with flag `-s` is used to translate all multiple consecutive spaces into a single space. Then, `cut` command return the 4th field using a single space as delimiter.

The advantage of piping commands is that one can make this process interactively. And whenever you aren't sure which flag to use, the manual pages are there to help: `man grep`, `man tr`, `man cut`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add awk to split the output,

```
mysqlthread=$(mysqladmin proc status | grep "Threads" | awk '{print $4}')
```

Comment: `grep "Threads" | awk '{print $4}'` = `awk '/Threads/{print $4}'`. You never need grep when you're using awk.